# Angular JS Routing Issue with Injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angular-ui-router

I am pretty new to Angular JS and am having an issue with injection according to the error I am getting.

[Error is here](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=navbarapp&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:modulerr%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.8%2F$injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Dui.router%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.4.8%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253Dui.router%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520Error%2520(native)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A6%253A416%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A24%253A186%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520b%2520(http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A23%253A251)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A23%253A494%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A38%253A117%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520n%2520(http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A333)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A37%253A488)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A38%253A134%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520n%2520(http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A333)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:6:416%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:38:391%0A%20%20%20%20at%20n%20(http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:7:333)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:37:488)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:38:134%0A%20%20%20%20at%20n%20(http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:7:333)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:37:488)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20eb%20(http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:41:249)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:19:463)

I am converting a template to get some practice.

I built a directive for the menu first

```
 app.directive("bsnavbar", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: "../components/navbar/Navbar.html",

        compile: function (element, attrs) {
            var li, liElements, links, index, length;
            liElements = $(element).find("#navbarul");

            if (attrs.currentTab === "Home") $(document.getElementById('homeLink')).addClass('active');
            if (attrs.currentTab === "About") $(document.getElementById('aboutLink')).addClass('active');
            if (attrs.currentTab === "Gallery") $(document.getElementById('galleryLink')).addClass('active');
            if (attrs.currentTab === "Contact") $(document.getElementById('contactLink')).addClass('active');
        }
    }
});
```

By itself it worked fine.

I then added some features to make a photo gallery more dynamic using controllers that read data from JSON files (this was still moving to separate pages gallery.html, gallery-1.html, etc when navigating)

```
var controllers = angular.module("controllers", []);

controllers.controller("GalleryPageCtrl", function GalleryPageCtrl($scope, $http, $stateParams) {
var gid = $stateParams.gid;

$scope.pageName = "Photography Gallery";
$scope.Description = "";
$http.get('/data/galleryItems.json')
                .then(function (response) { $scope.data = response.data.galleries });

});
```

again this worked fine.

Then I decided to condense down to using 1 page and html templates for injection using UI router.  Once I did this everything seemed to be fine and then I started to get an error.

Could this have something to do with how I have the HTML?

```
<body ng-app="navbarapp">

<div id="container">
    <header>
        <bsnavbar id="nbar" current-tab="Home"></bsnavbar>
    </header>



    <div ui-view>


    </div><!-- View End-->



</div> <!--Container End-->
.....
// Scripts and End body //
```

This is one of those hold ups that eats time.  I appreciate any help.

```
    <div class="preloader">
        <img alt="" src="images/preloader.gif">
    </div>
```

App Code

```
"use strict";

(function () {

var app = angular.module("navbarapp", ["controllers","ui.router"]);

app.directive("bsnavbar", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: "../components/navbar/Navbar.html",

        compile: function (element, attrs) {
            var li, liElements, links, index, length;
            liElements = $(element).find("#navbarul");

            if (attrs.currentTab === "Home") $(document.getElementById('homeLink')).addClass('active');
            if (attrs.currentTab === "About") $(document.getElementById('aboutLink')).addClass('active');
            if (attrs.currentTab === "Gallery") $(document.getElementById('galleryLink')).addClass('active');
            if (attrs.currentTab === "Contact") $(document.getElementById('contactLink')).addClass('active');
        }
    }
});


app.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state('Home', {
            url: '/',
            controller: 'HomePageCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'home',
            templateUrl: 'components/index/index.html'
        });



    $stateProvider
        .state('GalleryIndex', {
            url:'Gallery',
            controller: 'GalleryViewControl',
            controllerAs: 'GalleryIndex',
            templateUrl: 'components/gallery/galleryIndex.html'
        });

}]);

}());
```

Scripts

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="components/controllers/controllers.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.migrate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.imagesloaded.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/simpletextrotator/jquery.simple-text-rotator.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/retina-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/SmoothScroll.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
```

I investigated the script and for some reason using it locally i do not get that error message.  So i included it in the project.  I am still having an issue with the routing not working.  Using a url i get a 404 and the templates are not being displayed in the ui-view area.  The menu is working outside of the ui-view area.

I have tried adding

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
```

and updated

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider)
```

and am getting the injection error.  Every page I have found that discusses $urlRouterProvider so far states that it is a part of UI-Router.  Could this be an indication that my script is still not loading correctly?

Comment: Are you setting up a `.config` block with your states setup?

Comment: Can you post `app.js` code?

Comment: I am.  I updated my post as well with the app code.

Comment: Include the script tags in the HTML - obviously the ui.router module cannot be found... Did you include it?

Comment: yes, I am following step by step through a pluralsite class online as i am doing this. Unfortunately the videos works and mine does not.

Comment: Are you using the same version of Angular as in the Pluralsight course? If not, you could be running into an issue with some breaking changes. Also, what Pluralsight course is it?

Comment: Based on the error, I am seeing that it fails to load the ui.route module. I am not seeing app.js on your script calls (always worth checking...) also check if you are loading the ui-route js file (maybe its not found 404? ) also try replacing the order of your dependency in your app--> angular.module("navbarapp", ["ui.router","controllers"]);

Comment: The Pluralsite course is Angular Routing in Depth,  yes I am using the same angular.min.js file.

I tried changing the order of the dependencies, no luck.  Also my app.js is the controllers.js file they are all together.  Originally I was going from page to page and filtering what was displayed now I am trying to put everything onto a single page so I may need to separate the code into more files shortly.

Comment: My original app code is not from the pluralsite course and i had to modify it.  Originally it just was to control the navigation control.  When I added sref to nav instead of href the cursor no longer turns to a pointer and if i click the button to change views nothing happens. I am not getting the injection error any more but it is like the ui-router is not functioning.

Answer (score 0):

I changed how I wrote the code to below and it works fine.

```
angular.module('navbarapp').config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        controller: 'HomePageCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'Home',
        templateUrl: 'components/index/index.html'
    })
    .state('GalleryIndex', {
        url: '/Gallery',
        controller: 'GalleryViewControl',
        controllerAs: 'GalleryIndex',
        templateUrl: 'components/gallery/galleryIndex.html'
    });

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
});
```